# Binding object and widget together in Flutter using Provider package

Tags: flutter, state-management

Imagine in the TodoScreen of the application, I have a TodoObjectList (list of todos obtained from some API) and I want to show them inside a list. So I created a list of TodoWidgets (StatelessWidget), each one having its own TodoObject as its property. Now I want TodoWidgets to be bound with its TodoObject, so I used the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). The code is something like below (inside TodoScreen):

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<TodoObject>(
              builder: (_) => TodoObjectList[index],
              child: Consumer<TodoObject>(
                builder: (context, TodoObject, child) => TodoWidget(todo: TodoObject)
              ),
            );
    },
    childCount: TodoObjectList.length,
  ),
)
```

This code works fine for the first time. But when I go back and navigate to TodoScreen for the second time (I won’t call the API again, TodoObjectList is already cached), Provider throws an error:

```
 “A TodoObject was used after being disposed.”
```

I Know why this error is being thrown, but my question is how should I bind TodoWidget with TodoObject using provider, without facing this error when I have the API data stored somewhere.

Comment: Was having a similar issue and your question came up while searching. I found the following link helpful in my case: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-cupertino/#5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ChangeNotifierProvider.value instead. [This link](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) would probably help you if you had any follow up questions.